# Where is the define for the defconfig file to use in a yocto kernel recipie?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

How does a yocto bsp layer choose the defconfig?

Even in the examples or the documentation, the flow is not clear and I have no variable to actually change the defconfig file.
Nowhere in the linux recipe do I find the mention of the file `defconfig` for for that matter ARCH.

So here is my question, In case of a standalone kernel we have to do:

`ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make defconfig`

How is this provided in yocto bsp layer?

Even when I consider, the `poky/meta-yocto-bsp` and `poky/meta-skeleton`, I do not see ARCH specification. How do you specify the layer to compile kernel for arm64 defconfig?

How does a yocto bsp layer choose the defconfig?

Even in the examples or the documentation, the flow is not clear and I have no variable to actually change the defconfig file.
Nowhere in the linux recipe do I find the mention of the file `defconfig` for for that matter ARCH.

So here is my question, In case of a standalone kernel we have to do:

`ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make defconfig`

How is this provided in yocto bsp layer?

Even when I consider, the `poky/meta-yocto-bsp` and `poky/meta-skeleton`, I do not see ARCH specification. How do you specify witin the layer to compile kernel for arm64 defconfig?

To be clear, I am not talking about config fragments. I am talking about the primary defconfig itself.

Comment: Yocto takes configuration excerpts and merges them to a defconfig during the build, it doesn't have predefined file (however, you might patch kernel's one, of course). Read documentation about that.

Comment: Can you point me to the relevant documents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beaglebone / Yocto / Kernel configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111397/beaglebone-yocto-kernel-configuration)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301504/bitbake-append-file-to-reconfigure-kernel.

Comment: They are very informative but doesn't answer the question because the defconfig is already in the kern l repo. What's the need to supply it externally as a duplicate? I am looking for building the kernel simply with its URL, branch and revision using 'arch/arm64/config/defconfig'

Comment: I do know how to do this in Buildroot, but in Yocto you need a layer for that.